# KDE/Plasma and large monitor: how to snap windows to 3x3 grid?

Tags: monitors, plasma5, kde5

Doing a lot of software development I frequently need to see many windows at the same time. Thus I'm frequently arranging windows by dragging them to the left/right edge of the screen to scale them to 50% of the screen width or to one of the corners to adjust their size to a quarter of the screen size.

With 30 inch+ 4K+ monitors getting better and more affordable I'm wondering if there is a way to snap windows to a smaller grid (e.g. 3x3 or even 4x4). On Windows tools like [Dell Display Manager](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/qna44541/what-is-dell-display-manager?lang=en) seem to offer the kind of flexibility I'm looking for. Is there anything that can help me accomplish this? I have checked the KDE Store for [KWin Scripts](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/210/) but didn't find anything that would help me accomplish this.

I'm using KDE Plasma 5.18.5 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UltawideWindows kwin script should do what you are looking for. It maps shortcuts ctrl+meta+numpad and meta+numpad and ctrl+numpad and alt+numpad to map different window positions and sizes.

https://store.kde.org/p/1276605/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Krohnkite?

- https://store.kde.org/p/1281790/

But is uses dynamic tiling.